# Efficient way to change color blocks with timer

Tags: c#, timer, colors

I'm new to programming, I've been programming in C# for the last 3 months, and now I'm trying to make an app, on WP8.1, which consists in creating a screen with 4 blocks, assign a timer to it, and change the color of the 4 blocks as the timer "ticks".

The goal is that there is no repetitions in the color of the blocks (for example, if the first block is red, then it can't be blue or green...)

I have achieved my goal, but I think that my code is a little sloppy, and that's why I'm here..

```
public void ColorTimerChange(object sender, object args)
{
    count++;
    //Sets the text of a TextBlock so that I can check the time
    TimerTB.Text = count.ToString();
    //Creates a new Random instance
    Random rand = new Random();


    if (count % count == 0)
    {
        //Generates random numbers between 1 and 4 for every color.. If there are numbers that are equal, generate again
        RandBlue = rand.Next(1, 5);
        RandGreen = rand.Next(1, 5);
        RandRed = rand.Next(1, 5);
        while (RandBlue == RandGreen || RandBlue == RandRed || RandGreen == RandRed)
        {
            RandBlue = rand.Next(1, 5);
            RandGreen = rand.Next(1, 5);
            RandRed = rand.Next(1, 5);
        }
        //Textblocks so that I can check the random numbers 
        RedTB.Text = RandRed.ToString();
        RandomTB.Text = RandBlue.ToString();
        GreenTb.Text = RandGreen.ToString();


            switch (RandRed)
            {
               //if the random number for red is equal to 1, change the color of the 1st block to red. If the others random numbers are different to 2, change the color of the 2nd block to white, and so on.
                case(1):
                    {
                        Block1.Fill = color.Red;
                        if (RandGreen != 2 && RandBlue != 2)
                            Block2.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 3 && RandBlue != 3)
                            Block3.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 4 && RandBlue != 4)
                            Block4.Fill = color.White;
                        break;
                    }
                case (2):
                    {
                        Block2.Fill = color.Red;
                        if (RandGreen != 1 && RandBlue != 1)
                            Block1.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 3 && RandBlue != 3)
                            Block3.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 4 && RandBlue != 4)
                            Block4.Fill = color.White;
                        break;
                    }
                case (3):
                    {
                        Block3.Fill = color.Red;
                        if (RandGreen != 2 && RandBlue != 2)
                            Block2.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 1 && RandBlue != 1)
                            Block1.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 4 && RandBlue != 4)
                            Block4.Fill = color.White;
                        break;
                    }
                case (4):
                    {
                        Block4.Fill = color.Red;
                        if (RandGreen != 2 && RandBlue != 2)
                            Block2.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 3 && RandBlue != 3)
                            Block3.Fill = color.White;
                        if (RandGreen != 1 && RandBlue != 1)
                            Block1.Fill = color.White;
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }

            ...
}
```

This is the example for the color Red.. I did the same switch for the green and blue colors.
The colors are defined in the "Helperz.cs", which I created new SolidBrushColor(Colors.color) for every color that you find in my code.

How can I do the same thing, but without having to "copy" paste, and do the same thing over and over for every color/block.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. The Code Review stack exchange is a better place for questions of this type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your `Block`s in an array. Then you can simply say:

```
Blocks[RandRed] = Color.Red;
```

and the same for each other color.